# Cannot make Axis2 run with OSGi

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-axis

I want to build a client (just a client) with Axis2. I use Maven and OSGi (Felix). I manage to successfully install it using Maven, however when I run it using PAX provision, there come a bunch of error. This is my initial configuration in the POM (plus some more dependencies of AXIOM and WSDL4j).

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
  <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
  <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This builds fine, but when I do pax:provision I get

ERROR: Bundle axis2-transport-local [33] Error starting file:bundles/axis2-transport-local_1.6.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle axis2-transport-local [33]: Unable to resolve 33.0: missing requirement [33.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.axis2))org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle axis2-transport-local [33]: Unable to resolve 33.0: missing requirement [33.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.axis2)

Has anyone experienced something good with Axis2, OSGi, and Maven? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this axis2 jar already a osgi bundle? If not you need to create one, or find one already transformed. How about CXF? It's known to be working great with OSGi. 
Since your using Pax provisioning you might alos try to use the wrap command for wrapping the axis jar as a osgi bundle.

Comment: There is org.apache.axis2.osgi, which seems to be an OSGi bundle, but no success with it either. Yes, I am now considering using another stack like CXF

Comment: There should be quite a lot of samples around using CXF with OSGi, mostly using Karaf as container, with either Felix or Equinox as Framework.